# How can I delete display style from all children when I filter from bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to filter a collapse list as follow:

As you see there are a lot of div children when I filter some id.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
   var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#chartClass *").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xl-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <form class="form-inline d-flex justify-content-center md-form form-sm">
          <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <input id="myInput" class="form-control form-control-sm ml-3 w-75" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="chartClass">

  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstkonyahal">
    <div class="card" id="secondkonyahal">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderkonyahal">
        <h5><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdkonyahal" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdkonyahal collapsed " class="collapsed">konyahal</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdkonyahal" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivkonyahal" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 457px; top: 59px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label">2020-12-10</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: #0b62a4">
              Value:
              73
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firsteskisehirtb" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondeskisehirtb" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheadereskisehirtb" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdeskisehirtb" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdeskisehirtb collapsed " style="display: inline;">eskisehirtb</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdeskisehirtb" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDiveskisehirtb" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 0px; top: 84px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-05</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              22
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstkonyatb">
    <div class="card" id="secondkonyatb">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderkonyatb">
        <h5><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdkonyatb" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdkonyatb collapsed ">konyatb</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdkonyatb" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivkonyatb" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 49px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              19
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstankaratb" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondankaratb" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderankaratb" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdankaratb" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdankaratb collapsed " style="display: inline;">ankaratb</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdankaratb" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivankaratb" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 78px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              40
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstadanahal" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondadanahal" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderadanahal" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdadanahal" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdadanahal collapsed " style="display: inline;">adanahal</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdadanahal" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivadanahal" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 67px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              53
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstgapki" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondgapki" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheadergapki" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdgapki" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdgapki collapsed " style="display: inline;">gapki</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdgapki" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivgapki" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 35px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-09</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              1
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstmpob" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondmpob" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheadermpob" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdmpob" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdmpob collapsed " style="display: inline;">mpob</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdmpob" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivmpob" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 35px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-10</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              1
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstn11" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondn11" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheadern11" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdn11" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdn11 collapsed " style="display: inline;">n11</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdn11" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivn11" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 68px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              44
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstorkide" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondorkide" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderorkide" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdorkide" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdorkide collapsed " style="display: inline;">orkide</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdorkide" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivorkide" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 63px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              36
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firsthepsiburada" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondhepsiburada" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderhepsiburada" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdhepsiburada" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdhepsiburada collapsed " style="display: inline;">hepsiburada</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdhepsiburada" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivhepsiburada" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 59px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              64
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstedirnetb" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondedirnetb" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderedirnetb" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdedirnetb" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdedirnetb collapsed " style="display: inline;">edirnetb</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdedirnetb" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivedirnetb" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 211px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              2
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstpolatlitb" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondpolatlitb" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderpolatlitb" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdpolatlitb" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdpolatlitb collapsed " style="display: inline;">polatlitb</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdpolatlitb" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivpolatlitb" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 457px; top: 55px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-11</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              13
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstadanatb" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondadanatb" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderadanatb" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdadanatb" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdadanatb collapsed " style="display: inline;">adanatb</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdadanatb" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivadanatb" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 161px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              55
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstistanbultb" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondistanbultb" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderistanbultb" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdistanbultb" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdistanbultb collapsed " style="display: inline;">istanbultb</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdistanbultb" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivistanbultb" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 457px; top: 51px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-11</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              133
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstturib" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondturib" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderturib" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdturib" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdturib collapsed " style="display: inline;">turib</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdturib" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivturib" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 89px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              106
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I filter a section all children  `display: block` style turning to `display: none` because of that all children function turning to invisible.

So how can I delete `display: none` style from all children when I filter. Hope to find a way. Thank you for your help.

***Edit:***

When I search something I can just access the heading and all search child nodes disappear. For example, search "konya" in the snippet. I can see just heading all of the "konya" child nodes turning to the "hide" object.

I try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
   var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#chartClass *").filter(function() {    
          $(this).children("*:nth-child(n)").toggle($(this).children("*:nth-child(n)").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

But just first children turn to the visible. As you can see in the example one element has at least 2^n children's children.

Comment: You are calling `$(this).toggle(...)`, which will cause those elements to be `display: none;`.

Comment: I am trying to do filtering. Everything can be none except for my search and my search's all children but children are turning none too.

Comment: Please be more specific about which elements you want to hide. For example, you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65268319/edit) to include an example of how the HTML should look after user input.

Comment: I add more details @kmoser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want exactly but I hope that give an idea to you for find your own solution.

In this code; you can filter parent card div via value field;

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
   var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#chartClass .card").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle(
                $(this).find("h5>a").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1
          );
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xl-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <form class="form-inline d-flex justify-content-center md-form form-sm">
          <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <input id="myInput" class="form-control form-control-sm ml-3 w-75" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="chartClass">

  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstkonyahal">
    <div class="card" id="secondkonyahal">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderkonyahal">
        <h5><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" 
               data-target="#thirdkonyahal" aria-expanded="false"
               aria-controls="thirdkonyahal collapsed"
               class="collapsed">konyahal</a>
        </h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdkonyahal" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivkonyahal" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 457px; top: 59px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label">2020-12-10</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: #0b62a4">
              Value:
              73
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firsteskisehirtb" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondeskisehirtb" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheadereskisehirtb" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdeskisehirtb" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdeskisehirtb collapsed " style="display: inline;">eskisehirtb</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdeskisehirtb" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDiveskisehirtb" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 0px; top: 84px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-05</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              22
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstkonyatb">
    <div class="card" id="secondkonyatb">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderkonyatb">
        <h5><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdkonyatb" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdkonyatb collapsed ">konyatb</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdkonyatb" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivkonyatb" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 49px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              19
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstankaratb" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondankaratb" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderankaratb" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdankaratb" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdankaratb collapsed " style="display: inline;">ankaratb</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdankaratb" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivankaratb" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 78px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              40
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstadanahal" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondadanahal" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderadanahal" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdadanahal" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdadanahal collapsed " style="display: inline;">adanahal</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdadanahal" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivadanahal" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 67px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              53
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstgapki" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondgapki" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheadergapki" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdgapki" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdgapki collapsed " style="display: inline;">gapki</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdgapki" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivgapki" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 35px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-09</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              1
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstmpob" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondmpob" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheadermpob" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdmpob" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdmpob collapsed " style="display: inline;">mpob</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdmpob" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivmpob" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 35px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-10</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              1
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstn11" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondn11" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheadern11" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdn11" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdn11 collapsed " style="display: inline;">n11</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdn11" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivn11" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 68px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              44
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstorkide" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondorkide" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderorkide" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdorkide" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdorkide collapsed " style="display: inline;">orkide</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdorkide" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivorkide" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 63px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              36
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firsthepsiburada" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondhepsiburada" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderhepsiburada" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdhepsiburada" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdhepsiburada collapsed " style="display: inline;">hepsiburada</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdhepsiburada" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivhepsiburada" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 59px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              64
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstedirnetb" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondedirnetb" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderedirnetb" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdedirnetb" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdedirnetb collapsed " style="display: inline;">edirnetb</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdedirnetb" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivedirnetb" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 211px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              2
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstpolatlitb" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondpolatlitb" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderpolatlitb" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdpolatlitb" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdpolatlitb collapsed " style="display: inline;">polatlitb</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdpolatlitb" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivpolatlitb" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 457px; top: 55px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-11</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              13
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstadanatb" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondadanatb" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderadanatb" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdadanatb" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdadanatb collapsed " style="display: inline;">adanatb</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdadanatb" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivadanatb" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 161px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              55
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstistanbultb" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondistanbultb" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderistanbultb" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdistanbultb" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdistanbultb collapsed " style="display: inline;">istanbultb</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdistanbultb" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivistanbultb" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 457px; top: 51px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-11</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              133
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6" id="firstturib" style="display: block;">
    <div class="card" id="secondturib" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="card-header" id="firstheaderturib" style="display: block;">
        <h5 style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thirdturib" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdturib collapsed " style="display: inline;">turib</a></h5>
        <div class="float-right badge badge-success" style="font-size: 125%; display: block;">Basarili</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body collapse" id="thirdturib" style="display: block;">
        <div id="chartDivturib" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;">
          <div class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="left: 456px; top: 89px; display: block;">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label" style="display: block;">2020-12-12</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: rgb(11, 98, 164); display: block;">
              Value:
              106
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For example, when I call "konyahal", there are a lot of divs inside Konyahal. All those child divs disappear. (Mesela snippet te çalıştır konyahal aradığında onun içindeki "value","başarılı","tarih" kayboluyor sadece yazı kalıyor.)

Comment: I could not understand exactly how you want it to work. In which fields do you want to search for a sample value entered in the search box? How do you want the found elements to be displayed, can you explain with an example?

Comment: I want to search <div class="row" id="chartClass"> all children. When I enter "konya" I want to see "konyahal" and "konyatb" with their children elements (but there are 2^n children element in each search).

Comment: I will try and let you know to night. This edit makes more sense.

Comment: It works well it is too clear thank you so much :)